# (New to MATLAB) I want to learn how to use MATLAB to measure distances between features of an image. Where should I start?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I'm a grad student working on a PhD in a biomedical science and have no coding experience. My university has a campus license for MATLAB so I thought I'd try to learn how to use it to get a more quantitative handle on some of my images. Namely, I have a series of very similar images of cells (10-15 cells/image) migrating away from a tissue. I'd like to be able to use MATLAB to measure the distance between each cell and the tissue (normalized to the size of the tissue if possible). I've been reading about the tools available in the Computer Vision System Toolbox, such as object detection in a cluttered scene, but I'm not sure if they are relevant. I also don't know how to import my images into MATLAB. I'm not looking for someone to do all this stuff for me; rather, if someone could point me in the right direction (tools I should be looking at, helpful reading for beginners, etc), I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Matlab documentation contains getting-started guides for matlab environment and for each of the toolboxes. If you are a beginner, you can start with [matlab-getting-started](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html). Then you can get into toolboxes such as [image-processing](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/getting-started-with-image-processing-toolbox.html) and [computer vision](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/getting-started-with-computer-vision-system-toolbox.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fellow biomed PhD here :)

The Computer Vision Toolbox isn't really what you need, what you need for basic image manipulation tasks is the Image Processing Toolbox.
Go to the matlab documentation (which you can bring up with the `doc` command in the console) and if you have the Image Processing Toolbox installed there should be a link to its documentation from the documentation 'homepage'.

Alternatively, to get a (big) list of commands available in the image processing toolbox, type `help images` in the console. If you want to look for a particular keyword, you can use `lookfor`, e.g. if you type `lookfor distance` you will see one result for the `bwdist` command which calculates a distance transform.

The basic commands to read and display an image are `imread` and `imagesc`

Here's a small example of how you might use this to find cell distances. (run these commands line by line and see the result each time).

```
Img = imread('rice.png') % Read rice.png image into array I
```

(note: 'rice.png' is an image which comes ready in matlab and is in the matlab 'path' i.e. it is available for you to access regardless of the directory you're in at the moment. You can see where it is exactly on your computer by typing `which rice.png`. Also, you can suppress all that output after each command if you don't want it, by ending your command with a '`;`' )

`Img` is now a matrix containing interger values from 0 to 256 (i.e. of type 'unsigned integer'). Very often we work with 'grayscale' images in the range [0,1] instead (i.e. of type 'double').

```
Img = mat2gray(Img) % convert to grayscale image.
imagesc(Img) % visualise image
colormap gray % convert to grayscale colours
BinaryImg = (Img > 0.5) % retain only pixels with intensity above 0.5;
imagesc(BinaryImg) % visualise binary version
BinaryImg = bwareaopen(BinaryImg,10) % clean up image by removing objects less than 10 pixels big. type 'help bwareaopen' in the console for details
imagesc(BinaryImg) % see how the image has now cleaned up a bit
DistanceTransform = bwdist(BinaryImg)
imagesc(DistanceTransform) % each pixel value represents distance to nearest object (i.e. nearest 'true' pixel in binary image)
colorbar % helps you see what those distances are
colormap jet % this is a nicer map for distance images :)
```

Hope this helps a bit. Good luck with your journey :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Computer Vision Toolbox, especially matchFeatures function in the matlab documentation.

link: http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html